# Is a spline interpolation considered to be a nonparametric model?

Tags: nonparametric, terminology, splines, definition, interpolation

I am aware of the basic differences between [nonparametric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_statistics) and [parametric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_statistics) statistics. In parametric models, we assume the data follows a distribution and fit it onto it using a fixed number of parameters. With KDE for instance, this is not the case because we don't assume that the modeled distribution has a particular shape.

I am wondering how this relates to interpolation in general, and to spline interpolation in specific. Are all interpolation approaches considered to be nonparametric, are there "mixed" approaches, what is the case with spline interpolation?

Comment: You may be interested in the discussion in the comments thread to [Why are regression splines considered nonparametric models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/512424/1352)

Comment: I would say it depends on whether you treat eg number of knotpoints as fixed or not. I would argue polynomials are non parametric, cubics are parametric

Comment: @seanv507 Pretty sure that both the scalar multipliers and the exponents of polynomials are *precisely* and even *canonically* parameteric.

Comment: @alexis, my point is whether we treat the number of parameters fixed as in a cubic, or unlimited (eg across all polynomials)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a good question. Frequently, one will see smoothing regressions (e.g., splines, but also smoothing GAMs, running lines, LOWESS, etc.) described as **nonparametric regression** models.

These models are nonparametric in the sense that using them does not involve reported quantities like $\widehat{\beta}$, $\widehat{\theta}$, etc. (in contrast to linear regression, GLM, etc.). Smoothing models are extremely flexible ways to represent properties of $y$ conditional on one or more $x$ variables, and do not make *a priori* commitments to, for example, linearity, simple integer polynomial, or similar functional forms relating $y$ to $x$.

On the other hand, these models **are** parametric, in the mathematical sense that they indeed involve parameters: number of splines, functional form of splines, arrangement of splines, weighting function for data fed to splines, etc. In application, however, these parameters are generally not of substantive interest: they are not the exciting bit of evidence reported by researchers… the smoothed curves (along with CIs and measures of model fit based on deviation of observed values from the curves) *are* the evidentiary bits. One motivation for this agnosticism about the actual parameters underlying a smoothing model is that different smoothing algorithms tend to give pretty similar results (see Buja, A., Hastie, T., & Tibshirani, R. (1989). [Linear Smoothers and Additive Models](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1176347115). *The Annals of Statistics*, 17(2), 453–510 for a good comparison of several).

If I understand you, your "mixed" approaches are what are called "semi-parametric models". [Cox regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_hazards_model) is one highly-specialized example of such: the baseline hazard function relies on a nonparametric estimator, while the explanatory variables are estimated in a parametric fashion. GAMs—generalized additive models—permit us to decide which $x$ variables' effects on $y$ we will model using smoothers, which we will model using parametric specifications, and which we will model using both all in a single regression.

Comment: @whuber I would love your insight on how my answer works… and if you think I can improve it. My answer is informed by my understanding of a comment or two you have made over the years.

Comment: I like this answer (+1). Probably with the exception of Kaplan-Meier I can't think something that doesn't have some reasonable but core underlying statistical assumption. Realistically most smoothers assume some notion of local linearity.

Comment: Micro-nitpick: you can use splines in quantile regression just fine, so the centrality of $y$ is irrelevant. So here is my +1.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I adore nitpicky pedantry, and have modified my language. :D <3

Comment: +1. You write: "On the other hand, these models are parametric, in the mathematical sense that they indeed involve parameters". But this is not the definition of parametric as nonparametric models also involve parameters. To give a very concise (and possibly incomplete) definition: Parametric models can be represented in terms of a vector $\theta$ consisting of a finite number of real components. All other problems are called nonparametric. So it's still unclear to me if splines are parametric or not because for a fixed number of knots, the weights for the basis functions are of finite length.

Comment: @COOLSerdash Thank you! I think it is pretty clear that smoothing function indeed have a finite vector of $\theta$ real components that define the smoothing function. That said, my lack of pwn-level certainty on the topic around this exact point is why I begged for whuber's wisdom. :)

Comment: @COOLSerdash Any output of a computer can be described as a vector consisting of a finite number of real components.

Comment: @usεr11852 assumptions != parametric modeling. Even the famed Wilcoxon test, widely touted as a test of medians, is only a test of median when the distributions are symmetric.

Comment: +1 @AdamO *and* when the variances of those distributions are equal, I think?

Comment: @AdamO: Sure, I don't disagree.

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, every model is parametric in the sense of having parameters. When we speak of a "nonparametric model", we really mean a model with the number of parameters being manageable.

The technical definition of "nonparametric" just says "infinite or unspecified", but in practice it means "infinite, or so large that thinking in terms of the parameters becomes unwieldy and/or not useful". You give the example of a KDE, but a KDE is calculated from the sampled values, and the number of samples is finite, so the set of samples is technically a finite set of parameters.

If each spline has a finite number of parameters, and there is a finite number of splines, then it follows that the total number of parameters is finite, but practically speaking the number may be so large that it's not treated as parametric.

On the other hand, if the number of splines is small enough, and the models within the splines are simple enough, that may still be treated as being parametric. Other factors are whether there's a large collection of models with the same type of parameters (that is, the parameters have different values, but the parameters from one model are analogous to those of another), and how intuitive the meaning of the parameters are.

For instance, if you model the volume of $H_2O$ as a function of temperature, you'll probably want separate splines for ice, water, and steam. If you model each as being linear with respect to temperature, you have one coefficient of expansion for each phase (and probably different intercepts as well), which is a small enough number of parameters to being considered "parametric". You'll then also have solid, liquid, and gas coefficients of expansion for other substances.

In this case, the small number of parameters for a particular substance, the large number of substances that have those types of parameters, and the straight forward meaning of the parameters (how much does the substance expand when you heat it) contribute to it likely being considered a parametric model.