# Report non-linear term in a full regression model

Tags: cox-model, nonlinear-regression, reporting

Simple question about statistical reporting best practices.
I was asked to report the full model as a supplementary material of my paper. With the help of a toy example, let's say I have two variables in the model: var1 (linear) and var2 (modelled as a restricted cubic spline with 4 knots).

Here is the output:

```
  Coef    S.E.    Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)

 var1   -0.8754  0.0158  8.79  <0.0001 
 var2    4.5077  1.5089  2.99  0.0028  
 var2'  -0.1702  4.8386 -0.04  0.9719  
 var2'' -5.4636 12.5472 -0.44  0.6632
```

So the question is: how am I suppose to report this model in full, and particularly how to deal with non-linear terms?

My guess was to produce a table like this one:

| Variable | Coefficient | SE | p |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Var1 | -0.8754 | 0.0158 | <0.0001 |
| Var2 | 4.5077 | 1.5089 | 0.0028 |
| Var2 (non-linear term 1) | -0.1702 | 4.8386 | 0.9719 |
| Var2 (non-linear term 2) | -5.4636 | 12.5472 | 0.6632 |

But I am not sure this would be appropriate (especially referring to "non-linear term 1" and "non-linear term 2").

Can anyone help?

Comment: See my answer to [Is a spline interpolation considered to be a nonparametric model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/517781/is-a-spline-interpolation-considered-to-be-a-nonparametric-model/517784#517784), I think it may prove useful for you.

Answer (score 4):

I would keep the two sets of predictors separate as they convey different messages.

In `Var1` and `Var2` perhaps you may want to test if the relation between response and predictors is linear and significant.

The nonlinear spline terms, which are typically included for model flexibility, have more parameters and thus require specific explanation; for instance, here it's not obvious what `Coefficient`, `se` and $p$-values are referring to.

Comment: Clear. So how would you report this model in a scientific publication?
I strive to find any guidance on that, but never succeed.

Comment: @user89547235 How would you report any other four-feature regression model?

Comment: @Dave, well, I will produce a table like the one that I've posted, with coefficients and standard error for each variable included in the model.

But as I am aware that "coefficients" and "SE" are not easily interpretable for non-linear terms, I was wondering whether this approach is right in this context

Comment: I think that @whuber might have some thoughts on this.

Answer (score 4):

The individual coefficients for the spline can be difficult to interpret, and depend on the locations specified by the knots. The table that you propose might be included in supplemental material, but it's not going to be very helpful for presenting your results to your audience.

You need to document the magnitude and significance of the predictor as a whole and its combined non-linear terms.

For describing the magnitude of the association of `var2` with outcome, a plot of the predicted outcome values over a range of `var2` values, along with confidence intervals, is probably most informative. In your model, without interactions, you could choose any single value of `var1` to document that. That provides a visual display of any deviation from linearity.

For describing the significance of the association of `var2` with outcome overall and with respect to its non-linear terms, a set of "chunk" [Wald tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test) on combinations of coefficients is a good choice. That takes into account both the individual variances of the coefficient estimates and their covariances.

Overall, you test whether any of the 3 coefficients associated with `var2` is significantly different from zero.  You similarly test whether either of the 2 non-linear coefficients (`var2'`, `var2''`) is different from zero.

As these seem to be the types of coefficients reported by the `rcs()` function in Harrell's [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms), you can can do both of the above simply if you work with models produced by that package. You can use its `Predict()` function (capital "P") to get predictions for outcome as a function of `var2`, and plot with either base R graphics or with `ggplot()`. The `anova()` function applied to models from that package directly reports overall significance and significance of non-linear or interaction terms involving a predictor.